# Unable to import tensorflow_datasets ("not a mach-o file")

Tags: linux, zsh, package-management, python, macos

I have just set up my Mac M1 environment for tensorflow, and it seems to be running fine, the issue I'm having is setting up tensorflow_datasets. I installed this by running this in my conda env:

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-datasets
```

However, when I try to import it into a notebook, I get this error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/imadahmad/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/array_record/python/array_record_module.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/imadahmad/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/array_record/python/array_record_module.so' (not a mach-o file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/imadahmad/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/array_record/python/array_record_module.so' (no such file), '/Users/imadahmad/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/array_record/python/array_record_module.so' (not a mach-o file)
```

Do I need to rebuild the file so it is Mach-O type? I'm not fully sure why it's not running the .so file, I can find it in the given directory.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Search for `tensorflow "not a mach-o file"`, you'll find a few results that have possible solutions. If you can resolve this, please do [write an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). If not, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/742191/edit) the question and add what you tried to resolve it.